# List of domains ending

Tags: dns

I want to know all the possible endings of domains that can be recorded.

for example: .com, .net, .uk, .com.br

A list published on this?

Answer (score 4):

[Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/)

> A "public suffix" is one under which Internet users can directly register names. Some examples of public suffixes are ".com", ".co.uk" and "pvt.k12.wy.us". The Public Suffix List is a list of all known public suffixes.

Comment: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1

Answer (score 0):

You should not add a hard-coded list of valid top-level domains to your application.

Some applications have done this in the past, and the problem is that your list, while correct at the time you made it, will be out of date quite quickly.

For example, Zend Framework, misguidedly added a hard-coded list of top-level domains to its domain-name validator class. Now anyone who uses it will have a faulty application each time a new top-level domain is added, until they upgrade Zend Framework, which is a risky business as their entire application probably depends upon the consistent behaviour of many parts of it.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~nmelnick/Domain-PublicSuffix-0.04/lib/Domain/PublicSuffix.pm

Answer (score 0):

ICANN maintains the [list of Top-Level Domains](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registries/tlds). That being said, you should first read their article on [Universal Acceptance of All Top-Level Domains](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/tld-acceptance). To make it short:

> Most software should not need to test whether a domain name is valid. The act of connecting to a domain name […], or sending an email […] will automatically provide mechanisms of informing if the domain name is valid or not.
>
> If there is a need to check domain validity, it is most desirable that the DNS protocol is used for that purpose. If, however, there is a specific requirement to only check the validity of the top-level domain, a current list of all top-level domains that have been delegated within the authoritative root-server system is available [here](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registries/tlds).

Also note that “endings of domains that can be recorded” is a vague request. ICANN provides registration for top level domains. Registries provide for registration under their TLD (or a subdomain of their TLD). Other private actors also provide registration under their domain name. For example you can register a domain under `awsamazon.com`, `dyndns.org`, `free.fr` and many others.